# Sorting array in C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to sort an array size in C, i have ran some tests on it before i publish it here (I have left the testing statement in). 
I get the correct answer once but than it moves the higher value into the wrong array, even though i have used an IF statement.

If you guys run the program it will make sense to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
# define size 3

int sum();

main() {
    int a[size] = { 4, 2, 3 };
    int temp, i, j, x;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++){

        for (i = 1; i < size; i++){
            for (x = 0; x < size; x++){
                printf("%d", a[x]); //testing statement; 
            }
            printf("\n");
            if (a[j] > a[i]){
                temp = a[j]; 
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;

            }

        }

    }


for (x = 0; x < size; x++){
            printf("%d", a[x]);
        }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @e0k Why does the program move the element when the requirements for moving an element in the array are not met?

Comment: Note that your printing includes no newlines (so the numbers are all smushed together) and never identify which element of the array you're printing (so it is hard to know how the printing is relevant).  You'd need to fix that: `printf("a[%d] = %d\n", x, a[x]);` for example, though there are endless variations possible.  It might be best to have a function to dump the array on one line; it works nicely while you're dealing with small arrays of small numbers.

Comment: As to the moving problem, the chances are that your inner loop should index from `i+1`; at the moment, you'll compare `a[2]` with `a[1]` and move `a[2]` to `a[1]` if `a[2]` is bigger than `a[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for (i = 1; i < size; i++){
```

to something like

```
for (i = j + 1; i < size; i++) {
```

and your sort will work correctly. As it is, you're comparing the elements again with `if (a[j] > a[i]){` which can move them back when you reset `i` to `1`.

Comment: thank you that worked, but i am more interested in why that answer worked? I am more after the knowledge than the solution. 

Can you please give me a quick run down of why your solution worked and my'n didn't work?

Comment: @bahjat I tried too already, consider what is on the left hand side vs the right hand side when you allow `i` to be to the left of `j` in the `if`.